# Tamaño de la memoria en una descarga desde laravel

Tags: laravel, archivo, fileupload

estoy realizando una descargar desde laravel, el archivo está en un servidor y la conexión la realizo por sftp, el problema está con ficheros grandes.

El error me lo da con un fichero de 77MB

Tengo puesto el memory_limit a 512MB y he leido que puede ser un error de programación, para descarlo uso el Storage

```php
return Storage::disk('sftp')->download($fileDownload->file);
```

El error en concreto es este

```
Allowed memory size of 549453824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 616639928 bytes)
```

¿Como puedo solucionar esto?

También me he encontrado con otro problema, la subida de archivos grandes, he probado con el fopen pero nada (archivos de 1GB).

Comment: Quizá esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19509525/6459968) te pueda servir.

Answer (score 0):

post_max_size y upload_max_filesize son directivas que podes controlar desde  php.ini file o desde el archivo .htaccess o httpd.conf.

php.ini:

```
post_max_size=15M
upload_max_filesize=15M
```

.htaccess

```
php_value post_max_size=15M
php_value upload_max_filesize=15M
```

httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error.log
    <Directory /var/www/html/example/>
      AllowOverride None
      <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_value post_max_size=15M
        php_value upload_max_filesize=15M
      </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Esto en caso de ser problema del tamaño del archivo... y si llega a ser problema de memoria con el memory_limit lo solucionas, el problema de carga no variaría mucho segun el tamaño del archivo sino de los recursos que consuma el proceso de carga.